# Encrypt Windows exe files in Python

Tags: python, executable, exe

I am new to encryption in Python, I was wondering how I would go about encrypting a windows executable file?

Thanks

Comment: What does "encryption a windows executable file" mean? The phrase doesn't make sense. Do you mean "password protect"? Do you mean "encrypt the file", which makes it non-executable? Please edit to make it more clear what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to "write a Python program to encrypt an .exe", then just encrypt it (or decrypt it) as you would any other file.  For example: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot effectively encrypt an `exe` file, nor can you encrypt a python program.  At some point, you must reveal the secret to the computer and its user will be there when you do.

You can, however, strive at some terribly ineffective methods for making it mildly difficult to get at the algorithm being executed.  These methods include:

- http://www.py2exe.org/
- http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html
- http://www.bitboost.com/#Python_obfuscator